# mod_rewrite: Redirect everything to / (docroot)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site which has only ONE file: `index.html`.

I just want to redirect **everything** *except* for http://www.mysite.com/ to http://www.mysite.com/.

That includes `/index.html`, `somephonydir/`, `somefile.txt`, you name it -- I don't care what it is, I just want to redirect to `/`.

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L]
```

This gives me a 500 Internal Server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I guess I forgot to actually tell it to redirect. ;)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$  /
```

Comment: Thanks tmg, but I tried that too. I finally figured it out myself. :)